# Перенос сайта на wordpress. "Не удалось найти IP-адрес сервера wpfolder."

Tags: wordpress, openserver

Перенес сайт с локального openserver на платный хостинг. Перенес дамп базы данных.
Файлы wordpress поместил в папку public_html.
Поменял значения в wp-config.php, в базе данных в wp_options поменял значения home и siteurl на текущий. Все равно отображается вот это.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы проверил url в браузере для начала

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow ru! Почитайте о том, как надо переносить сайт на WP: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562